# Define object thickness with curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, drivers

I'm modeling a heart-shaped cookie cutter, and I'd like its cross section to be thicker near the top and come close to a point at the bottom. The heart is a Bezier curve with a mirror modifier, extruded so it's 2.5cm tall (z-dimension).

I've made a 2D Bezier curve which I would like to use to define the thickness of the heart. It's the same height as the heart, and for any given z-value, I want the heart's thickness to be equal to the curve's x-value.

I've added a solidify modifier to the heart, and I think a driver might be appropriate for the thickness parameter, but I'm struggling to make it work. Is a driver the right thing for this? Any additional direction would be appreciated.

[image]